# Can Mac and Window users work together with openJDK8 using Eclipse?

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, macos

Our team wants to use openJDK 8 (javac 1.8.0_265) on both mac and windows using Eclipse(2018-09).

Will there be any problems when sharing files etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could run into problems if you use the tab (HT) character for indentation.  The default tab width on Mac OS is 8 spaces, but on Windows it is default.  If you don't necessary steps, code written on Mac OS will look mis-indented on Windows and vice versa.

A solution:  Make it part of your coding conventions that only space (SP) characters shall be used for indentation.  Get everyone to adjust their IDE / editor settings to do this automatically.

Comment: Thank u for your advice Stephen :)

Answer (score 0):

Java is compile once run anywhere
compilation depends upon JDK. As it's same there won't be any issues

Comment: Thank you so much now I can go to bed happily XD